# Applying the Chain Rule to solve integral inequality

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, integral-inequality

I have the next exercise:

> Suppose that $f$ has a decreasing derivative which satisfies $f'(x) \geq m \geq 0$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$ prove that: $$\left| {\int_a^b \cos(f(x))dx}\right| \leq \frac {2}{m}$$

As a hint, I've got to first multiply and divide my function with $f'(x)$ and then apply this:

> If $f'$ is integrable and $g$ continuous  in $[a,b]$. Then exist $c \in [a,b]$ such that $$\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx = f(a) \int_a^c g(x)dx + f(b) \int_c^bg(x)dx$$

I've already tried but I get a little bit confused using the Barrow's rule to get my integral and also applying the inequality $f''(x)\leq 0$ to get the main inequality.

Comment: Are you sure you're not supposed to use the chain rule? That would result in something like $\cos(fx) \,\mathrm{d}x = \cos(f(x)) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{f'(x)} \leq \cos(u) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{m}$. After that it's just a matter of showing the integral of $\cos(u)$ won't every give a result greater than 2, which can easily be shown by just evaluating the integral.

Comment: @Contravariant $\cos(f(x))\frac{\mathrm{d}f(x)}{f'(x)} \leq \cos(u) \, \frac{\mathrm{d}u}{m}$ is not necessarily true as $\cos(f(x)) \not\geq 0$.

Comment: @Delta-u Ah that's right, I suppose that's what the condition that $f'$ is decreasing is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you already managed to derive something similar to the following:

$$
\def\d{\mathrm{d}}
\begin{align}
\left|\int_a^b \cos(f(x)) \, \d x \right|
&= \left|\int_a^b \frac{\cos(f(x))}{f'(x)} f'(x) \, \d x \right|\\
&= \left|\frac1{f'(a)}\int_a^c \cos(f(x)) f'(x) \, \d x + \frac1{f'(b)}\int_c^b \cos(f(x)) f'(x) \, \d x \right|\\
&= \left|\frac1{f'(a)}(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + \frac1{f'(b)}(\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|\\
&=\frac1{f'(b)}\left|\frac{f'(b)}{f'(a)}(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + (\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|
\end{align}
$$

Now the thing to note here is that $f'(a)\geq f'(b) \geq 0$ so $\frac{f'(b)}{f'(a)} \in [0,1]$. This allows us to find the upper bound as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
\frac1{f'(b)}&\left|\frac{f'(b)}{f'(a)}(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + (\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|\\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]} \left|\lambda(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + (\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|\\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]} \left|\lambda(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + \lambda(\sin(b)-\sin(c)) + (1 - \lambda)(\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|\\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]}  \bigl|\lambda(\sin(b)-\sin(a)) + (1-\lambda)(\sin(b) - \sin(c))\bigr|\\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]} \lambda|\sin(b)-\sin(a)| +  (1-\lambda)|\sin(b) - \sin(c)| \\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]} \lambda2 + (1-\lambda)2  \\
&\le \frac2{f'(b)} \le \frac{2}{m}
\end{align}
$$

Basically what we used here is the fact that the absolute value is a convex function, in the sense that for all $x,y$ and  $\lambda\in[0,1]$:

$$|\lambda x + (1-\lambda)y| \leq \lambda|x|+ (1-\lambda)|y|.$$

In fact since we're maximizing a convex function on a convex set we could have immediately concluded that the maximum had to be at the boundary, i.e. $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$, both giving an upper bound of $\frac{2}{m}$, but in your case you probably can't just state that without proof.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more this inequality:
\begin{align}
\frac1{f'(b)}&\left|\frac{f'(b)}{f'(a)}(\sin(c)-\sin(a)) + (\sin(b)-\sin(c))\right|\\
&\le \frac1{f'(b)} \max_{\lambda\in[0,1]}  \bigl|(1-\lambda)(\sin(b) - \sin(c)) + \lambda(\sin(b)-\sin(a))\bigr|
\end{align}, I don't understand how you obtain it. Thanks :-)

Comment: @Delta-u I've added some extra intermediate steps. Let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: It is perfectly clear now, thank you :-)